# Regular expressions with empty set/empty string

Tags: regular-expressions

I was wondering if expressions such as:

$λ*$

$∅*$

$λ+∅$

$∅λ$

are considered valid expressions. If so, how can I explain them?

also if $∅λ$ is valid, does that imply $∅λ∅λ∅λ∅λ∅λ∅λ$ is valid, or $∅∅∅∅∅∅∅∅∅λ$ is also valid for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  One has

$$\begin{align}
\lambda\ast & = \lambda\\
\emptyset\ast &= \lambda \\
X + \emptyset &= X\text{ for all $X$ } \\
\emptyset X &= \emptyset\text{ for all $X$} \\
\lambda X &= X\text{ for all $X$ } \\
\end{align}$$

These all follow directly from the definitions of the various operations.
For example, $A+B$ is defined as the set of strings that are in $A$ or in $B$.  When $B=\emptyset$, there are no strings in $B$, so $A+\emptyset = A$ for any $A$.

Similarly $AB$ is defined to be the set of all strings of the form $ab$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.  When $B=\emptyset$, there are no such strings, because there is no possible choice of $b\in \emptyset$, so $A\emptyset = \emptyset$.  In particular, $\emptyset\emptyset\emptyset\emptyset\emptyset\emptyset\emptyset\emptyset\emptyset\lambda = \emptyset$.

Comment: When converting an automata to a regular expression and i have 0+(emptyset)1 does emptyset concatenated with 1 = emptyset. Im talking about emptyset concatenated with a string instead of a set

Comment: With regular expressions, things that look like strings actually represent sets—sets with only one element. And $\varnothing$ concatenated with anything is still $\varnothing$.